# MySQL best practices for huge table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, amazon-rds

I need help guys. I am no db expert and try to learn.

1)

I have a table with 45 columns and 100m records. (adding ~1 million every hour)
I need to generate reports from this table. When the row counts were only a few hundreds, my query was sth like this and working pretty well:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE EVENT_TYPE WHEN 'imp' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as imps, 
    COUNT(CASE EVENT_TYPE WHEN 'click' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as clicks, 
    COUNT(CASE EVENT_TYPE WHEN 'pc_conv' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as post_click_convs, 
    COUNT(CASE EVENT_TYPE WHEN 'pv_conv' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as post_view_convs, 
    SUM(booked_revenue_dollars) as booked_revenue, 
    TRIM(site_domain) as site_domain, 
    campaign_id 

FROM 
    lld_standards 

WHERE 
    `datetime` >= '2014-05-10 00:00:00' AND `datetime` <= '2014-05-10 23:59:00'

GROUP BY 
    campaign_id, 
    site_domain

HAVING
    COUNT(CASE EVENT_TYPE WHEN 'imp' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 100;
```

I created index for `datetime`
For most reports, only the `GROUP BY` part changes.

**So how can I improve the query?**

2)

I am using RDS now (m3.large) and planning to switch to Redshift. **Do you think it is the right move now?**

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Here is the result of EXPLAIN:
[image: EXPLAIN]

Comment: Are you only inserting or also updating the database and is this the "main" query or just one of many?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson no updates, only inserts.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson this is one of many but for most of the others, only the "group by" part changes.

Comment: @Strawberry I added the results of EXPLAIN.

Comment: As far as I can see, grouping by a calculated field (site_domain) is your biggest problem. Any way to trim the value _before_ inserting it instead of in the query?

Comment: In fact, i never thought it would matter. Of course I can make that trimming before inserting.

Comment: I can't say for sure that it will improve the query without other changes, but always prefer processing before insert (it can even be done in code so that your database doesn't need to trim) to processing in the query if the effect is the same. If nothing else, it will allow you to add more effective indexing. At the moment it does not look like your datetime index is even used.

Answer (score 3):

With the index, your query is about as efficient as you can make it in MySQL.  The challenge is aggregating 24 million rows for each day.  MySQL is not really efficient at aggregation, as noted by the use of "filesort" in the explain plan.

If you are dealing with days of data, then you should consider a partitioning scheme, so each of data is stored in its own partition.  See more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html).  This would probably make the fetching of the data a bit faster, but the real time sink is the `group by`.  Any method you can use to reduce the number of rows being aggregated would make that go faster.

The question about switching to RedShift is more opinion based, so I will give a short, personal answer.  In my experience with RedShift, I have been positively impressed by the performance and think it would work well on your query.

Comment: Thank you! I added one last question, can I have your comments on this one too: "Is NoSQL suitable here?"

Comment: @ekrembk . . . That, unfortunately, makes the question no longer appropriate for Stack Overflow, because it invites opinion and extended discussions.  I'm sure NoSQL aficionados would say "yes".  My personal opinion is more biased toward SQL for analytic purposes.